# Is it possible to hide the header of an empty table in Ant Design?

Tags: reactjs, antd

This is my table
[Table with no data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OO5K5.png)

My table has a default filtering on a column.

```
const columns = [
...other_columns,
    {
      title: 'Requester',
      dataIndex: 'requester',
      key: 'requester',
      width: '10%',
      defaultFilteredValue: 'User1',
      ...getColumnSearchProps('requester', searchInput, handleSearch, handleReset, filterObj),
    },
]
```

When the table is empty i want to show the user another layout instead of the table. I tried using `locale` prop that the table provides but i want to hide the header and create something like this. Does antd provide a prop for that? Or is there any hack available to achieve this? [No table when no data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dcqf.png)

Answer (score 5):

Use the showHeader prop on Table

```
showHeader={empty ? false : true}
```

Comment: what condition do i provide to check if the data being passed to the table is empty or not?

Comment: if you share the whole component, can help more

Answer (score 0):

It is up to you if you don't want to show the table component when there is no data. If I got you right you want to hide the whole table if there is no data. In that case, you can create a parent component that will manage which component to show. Something like this

```
const SomeParentComponent = (data) => {
  return data.length ? <Table columns={data} ... /> : <YourCustomComponent ... />
}
```

Comment: when i use defaultFilteredValue for a column, the data being passed to the table does not change. Antd table internally decides the rows to be filtered.

Comment: Aha, I didnt get you. I dont know how you can do it on ant table or is it possible.